# Displaying a symbol µ

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

I have `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />` in the header, but it still shows `�` instead of `µ`. I tried adding `AddCharset UTF-8 .php` to `.htaccess`, but it didn't help.

**EDIT:** if I just put symbol `µ` in the file, it displays correctly. I get `�` when I try to output it from a database.

Comment: Is your **file** actually encoded in UTF-8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If something displays as the � UNICODE REPLACEMENT CHARACTER, that means the document is interpreted in a Unicode encoding (e.g. UTF-8) but the byte sequence at this point is invalid in this encoding.

In other words, your data/file is not UTF-8 encoded. Make sure it's *saved as UTF-8*, not just *declared* as such.

If you have problems outputting it from a database, it means the data coming from the database is not UTF-8 encoded. See [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/).

Answer (score 0):

You get this problem because your output actually is not UTF-8, even though you tell the browser that it is. You should fix that problem.

If you fix it by correcting the output so it is proper UTF-8, then your problem will be fixed, because UTF-8 can display this symbol (and any other). If you fix it by changing the charset to an ANSI character set, then you will have output in a codepage that may not support this symbol.

To output it correctly, you can output it as a html entity, either `&micro;` or `&#181;`. If you do this now, the symbol will also display correctly, but remember that your actual output is not UTF-8, so if you need another symbol on your page, then you'll have the same problem!

**Edit**

I see your edit now. If it works with a hard coded character, then the PHP is right, but the fetched data doesn't have the proper encoding. You can solve this by giving your database, table and/or the specific column any of the unicode collations. An alternative method would be to use the function [iconv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) to convert the data from your database to UTF-8 after you query it.

Comment: comment on my answer while you say the same...

Comment: @Bjorn That's not true. If you look very closely, then you see that instead of a picture of a table, my answer contains some text explaining the problem instead of just specifying a workaround